# Forcing document re-render upon CSSStyleDeclaration update (chrome)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, media-queries

(CHROME ONLY) I'm trying to modify media-query related CSSRules at runtime, however, when I modify the rules, the document is not re-rendering.  The document will only re-render when the media queries change again.  If you look at the fiddle you'll notice that upon load, the element is a dark color, when it should be red immediately.  Is there a way to ask the document to invalidate the styles?

You'll see that the style changed successfully if you move the browser window smaller, and than larger again so that it invalidates the media query styles twice.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QNgxk/3/

**edit: sometimes the fiddle works ???  yikes**

code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">I SHOULD BE RED</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
    position: absolute;
    width:    100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height:   50px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    #test {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');   // get the element
var rules = window.getMatchedCSSRules(test);  // get matched rules
var regexp = new RegExp('^#test');            // test the CSS rule explicit id
var matchedRule;
for (var i = rules.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // loop through rules and find the explicit one
    var rule = rules[i];
    if (rule.cssText.match(regexp)) {
        matchedRule = rule;
        break;
    }
}

// now change the rule to have a background of red, and width 20%
if (matchedRule) {
    matchedRule.style.setProperty('background-color', '#f00');
    matchedRule.style.setProperty('width', '20%');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I am just writing this here in case it might help someone else.
For me the test to match the rule was incorrect. In FireFox it functioned as the selectorText is as it is written in the stylesheet but Chrome converts all the names to lower case. So this test would not match in Chrome:

```
if(theRules[i].selectorText == ".myRule pre"){
```

Would match in FireFox but Chrome changed the selector text to be lower case so thus:

```
.myrule pre
```

So changing the code to this:

```
if(theRules[i].selectorText.toLowerCase() == ".codemirror pre"){
```

Fixed the issue so it works in both browsers. By the way the setProperty works for me in Chrome 30. Reason I am using it is because it allows to specify important thus:

```
theRules[i].style.setProperty("font-size", this.editorFontSize+"px", "important");
```

Hope this helps.